Golang 1.23: Is there anyway to preserve timestamps using os.DirFS and os.Copy FS
I realize these are brand new features in 1.23. I noticed that when using os.CopyFS that all timestamps are being set to the time when the function is called. I'm assuming this is just how it is, but am asking in case I missed something. I don't see anything in the source.
I currently use github.com/otiai10/copy which implements an Options type that provides a bool to set whether or not the timestamps are preserved. But, I've wanted to move to away from the library because of it's use of the x/sync and x/sys modules.
Thanks in Advance!

Maybe just copy the little routine that does that: https://github.com/otiai10/copy/blob/v1.14.0/preserve_times.go  It looks like it's Linux-only :-(

No it’s not builtin, and it needs to be filesystem specific. If you don’t want to keep that dependency, you will need to rewrite what it does.

@JimB Thanks. I'll try walking the fs, grabbing the fileinfo, then reapplying to the copied files.

@JimB answered the question in comments:

No it’s not builtin, and it needs to be filesystem specific. If you don’t want to keep that dependency, you will need to rewrite what it does.

